# METEOR_SETTINGS env variable does not populate Meteor.settings

Tags: meteor

I run a Meteor app locally on an OS X system and I use a `meteor-settings.json` file:

```
$ cat meteor-settings.json
{
  "public": {
    "s3path": "https://d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net"
  }
}
```

When I run meteor as following:

```
$ meteor --version
Meteor 1.2.1
$ meteor --settings meteor-settings.json
```

`Meteor.settings.public.s3path` has the expected s3 url and everything works great.

According to the [official Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settings) I can use the `METEOR_SETTINGS` environment variable. Problem is, when I populate and export it (as following):

```
$ export METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat meteor-settings.json)
$ echo $METEOR_SETTINGS
{ "public": { "s3path": "https://d2v4p3rms9rvi3.cloudfront.net" } }
$ meteor
```

`Meteor.settings.public` becomes empty, and all s3-url-based functionality is broken.

Without using the env variable I can't bundle and simulate a production deploy, because afaik production deploys cannot use command line flags (at least on AWS/EBS).

Why does Meteor not populate `Meteor.settings.public`? Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 6):

The salient line in the docs is this:

> When running your server directly (e.g. from a bundle), you instead specify settings by putting the JSON directly into the METEOR_SETTINGS environment variable.

When they say "running your server directly (e.g. from a bundle)" they mean using meteor build, and then running the resulting bundle using node. The meteor command won't pick up METEOR_SETTINGS by design, as METEOR_SETTINGS is only for production.

For Amazon, try something like this:

```
METEOR_SETTINGS={"public": {"key": "ABC"}} node main.js
```

Set the environment variable inside the command to run your meteor app. Not sure if that will work on Amazon.

Comment: Thanks! That clarifies it! As proven often, carefully rtfm seems to prove itself :) As for Amazon - individual aws environment configs offer a key/value input page for the environment variables, so that should work. If not, I'll post an update